# Vigenere cipher not working

Tags: python, encryption, vigenere

So my teacher created this vigenere cipher and he said it was working.
However, after checking its results with online vigenere ciphers it appears to not be resulting with the correct encryptions.

I have no idea how to fix it and I was wondering if someone could direct me to the errors, and tell me how to fix them.

Here is the code

```
base = ord("a")
alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'  
keyword = input('What is your keyword')
message = input('What is your message to be coded or encoded?').lower()

expandedKeyword = ""
while len(expandedKeyword) < len(message): 
    for i in keyword:
        if len(expandedKeyword) < len(message): 
            expandedKeyword += i 


cipheredMessage = '' 
indexofKeyword = 0
for i in message:
        if i == ' ':
            cipheredMessage = cipheredMessage + " "
        else:
            shiftedIndex = (ord(i) + ord(expandedKeyword[indexofKeyword])-base) % 26 +base
            cipheredMessage = cipheredMessage + chr(shiftedIndex)
            indexofKeyword = indexofKeyword + 1



print(cipheredMessage)
```

I understand the concept of what is happening, but I cant seem to figure out the error.

Comment: "after checking its results with online vigenere ciphers it appears to not be resulting with the correct encryptions." Ok, cool. Can you give an example of what kind of input you tried, what output you got, and what output you expected to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of `shiftedIndex` is wrong, you need to subtract `base` twice , but you are currently only subtracting it once. Example -

```
shiftedIndex = (ord(i) + ord(expandedKeyword[indexofKeyword])-2*base) % 26 +base
```

This is because you need to subtract `base` first time from `ord(i)` to get the index of i (from `'a'`) , and the second time from `ord(expandedKeyword[indexofKeyword])` , to get the index of that character (from `'a'` ) . So it should look like (for better understanding) -

```
shiftedIndex = ((ord(i) - base) + (ord(expandedKeyword[indexofKeyword])-base)) % 26 + base
```